# Different implementation of reverse linked list

Tags: php, data-structures, linked-list

I have found several reverse linked list implementation in php and most of them are the same with some little differences like this:

```
public function reverse() {
    if ( $this->_firstNode !== NULL ) {
        if ( $this->_firstNode->next !== NULL ) {
            $reversed = $temp = NULL;
            $current = $this->_firstNode;
            while ( $current !== NULL ) {
                $temp = $current->next;
                $current->next = $reversed;
                $reversed = $current;
                $current = $temp;
            }
            $this->_firstNode = $reversed;
        }
    }
}
```

But I think it could be changed to this:

```
public function reverse() {
    while ( $this->_firstNode->next !== NULL ) {
        $oldFirstNode = $this->_firstNode;
        $this->_firstNode = $oldFirstNode->next;
        $oldFirstNode->next = NULL;
        $this->_firstNode->next = $oldFirstNode;    
    }
}
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work, for two reasons:

1. You do not test for empty list. The method does not consider the case in which `$this->_firstNode` is `NULL`.
2. The method does not work if the list contains only one element.
3. If the list contains two or more elements, the method reverses only the first two elements of the list, then it falls in an endless loop. This is because in the last line of the body of the while you update `$this->_firstNode->next` with the value of `$oldFirstNode`, and in the next iteration you check for  `$this->_firstNode->next !== NULL`, which is different from `NULL` since it is the value of `$oldFirstNode`, and the function continue looping on those two nodes.

For algorithm like this one, the best approach is to use paper and pencil and sketch the elements of the list and the variables pointing to them, and update them by following the algorithm step by step.

Finally note that if an algorithm is always is used for a certain basic task, it is very difficult to find a new, more efficient, algorithm.